# Gson + Retrofit, how does it work?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to make API requests. The thing is, project hasn't been written by me and currently i'm rewriting API calls, because they were made with manual HttpRequest structure. The issue, is that for some reason to field "photoUrl" if there is none server returns value "false", which is bad, but question was constructed due to this issue. So, that's the field:

```
private String photoUrl;
```

I assumed that when Retrofit response will be converted to object, setter will be used to set a value, so temporary i've made a condition to set it as `null` if "false" is coming to prevent issues in further user interaction with an app, here's setter:

```
public void setPhoto_url(String photoUrl) {
    if(!photoUrl.equals("false")) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

To my surprise, condition is not working at all, and that is what raised my question : **Isn't Gson supposed to use setter to set value to private field?**

Comment: please check  is it string value that you used `false`

Comment: @Saveen, thx for the reply, but if it's not, how does Gson correctly converting it to string?

Comment: you can check it before setting any value and if check is correct then it work in setter as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, GSON uses reflection to set the field value directly.

It does not use getters/setters, and doesn't have the option of using getters/setters either.

Comment: But who's doint this : field.setAccessible(true); ? Gson itself?

Comment: And other one: then i can't controll at all which value will be set, and can't set this check at all?

Comment: You can define type adapters manually to override this behavior though if I recall right.

Comment: What exactly you mean? Like to throw away Gson and parse Json manually?

Comment: @NikMyers personally I like the library [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) instead of GSON, because it picks up getters/setters (if the field is not public), instead of using reflection/direct field access.

Comment: I'd advise against using GSON dtos as your model classes. I usually transform all those filthy dtos into immutable model classes where I can enforce my own checks.